# Proving that $f=x\cdot g(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$ exists.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

> Let $f$, $g$ two functions that are defined on a neighborhood of $0$ such that $f(x)=x\cdot g(x)$ for every $x$ in that neighborhood. Then $f$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$ exists.

Okay so I'm stuck in the second direction. If I assume $g(x)$ has a limit, where does it get me?
The first direction is quite straightforward.

Assume $f$ is differentiable at $0$, then the limit of $\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)\right)}{x-0}$ exist, and is equal to some $L ∈ R$.

Then we have

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)\right)}{x}=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x\cdot g\left(x\right)-0\cdot g\left(0\right)\right)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x\cdot g\left(x\right)\right)}{x}=\lim_{x\to \:0}g(x)=L$

Therefore $\lim_{x\to \:0}g(x)$ exist, and is equal to $L$.

Assume $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$ exists, and is equal to some $L ∈ R$.

But this can also be written as

$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\cdot x}{x}=\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{x}=L$

Now we check if $f$ is differentiable at $0$

$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)\right)}{x-0}=\lim \:_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-0\cdot g\left(0\right)\right)}{x}=\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{x}=L$

Therefore the limit exists and $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Note that $f(0)=0$, so for a neighborhood of $0$ without the $0$, you can just write $(f(x)-f(0))/(x-0) $ which is $f(x)/x$ and by definition this is $g$, So if there exists the limit of $g$, then $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: This is correct.............

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! I've added the second direction once I was able to solve it in case someone from the future will be interested in this question! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)=xg(x)$ (in a neigbourhood of $0$) then $f(0)=0.$ Thus we have (for any $x\ne 0$)

$$\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=g(x),$$ from where

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x).$$

In other words, $f$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ exists.

**EDIT**

If $f$ is differentiable at $0$ then there exists $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}.$ Thus there exists $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ and it takes the value $f'(0).$

Conversely, assume that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ exits. Since $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ we can say that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and moreover $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x).$

Comment: Don't I need to prove the second direction? Because what you posted is basically what I did in the main post.

Comment: I am not sure about what you are asking. I have editted the answer for clarification.